# Linear algebraic methods to compute Gröbner bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algorithms, groebner-basis

I know of the famous Buchberger algorithm to find Gröbner bases. However I am curious if it is not somehow possible to compute them using only linear algebra.

---

**Own Work:** The little I know so far is that

1. It is possible to represent multiplication of polynomials as convolutions of their coefficients. 2D convolution if 2-variable polynomial, 3D convolution if 3-variable et.c.
2. Then I know we can represent convolution of 1D vectors by multiplication by Toeplitz matrices, and my suspicions are that we should be able to do the same for higher number of dimensions..

Should not this provide at least a tool to set up equation systems governing products of multivariate polynomials?

Comment: "In computer algebra, the Faugère F4 algorithm, by Jean-Charles Faugère, computes the Gröbner basis of an ideal of a multivariate polynomial ring. The algorithm uses the same mathematical principles as the Buchberger algorithm, but computes many normal forms in one go by forming a generally sparse matrix and using fast linear algebra to do the reductions in parallel." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faug%C3%A8re%27s_F4_and_F5_algorithms

Comment: @SergioParreiras sounds very interesting, thank you. Feel free to make it an answer if you want.